# Using wrapper classes - java

Tags: java

I described my previous problem here:
[Java - how can I loop methods with same name but different parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30806289/java-how-can-i-loop-methods-with-same-name-but-different-parameters/30806745#30806745)

And I have question related to that.

Is given there example - a good example of using wrapper class?

```
class Wrapper{
  Part param1;
  File param2;
  File param3;
}

class Validator{
  void validate (Wrapper wrapper);
}


class ValidatorA extends Validate{
 void validate (Wrapper wrapper){
    //use wrapper.part... 
 }
}

class ValidatorC extends Validate{
 void validate (Wrapper wrapper){
    //use wrapper.file... 
     }
}
```

But it makes me wonder. Is wrapper correct name for it? Is is valid wrapper class? From what I read wrapper classes are used for primitives to use them as objects, shouldn't then it be named different? Or am I wrong?

I need it to be called same way, so I can loop over it so overloading is not the answer. Given class works fine - I just think if is it correct way to use wrapper name?

Comment: IMHO as of now, the class name has no meaning. How would another developer understand the purpose of the class? It has three fields, how are they related?

Comment: It holds all arguments needed for all validators

Answer (score 0):

Wrapper is not good choice in this case. Usually wrapper is used to wrap some different things so they look alike even they are totally different. For example you may have some stream of data which comes from different sources - file, http connection, resources. All what you care is to read data from this source. So, you write wrapper which reads from any source and just deliver data.

Wrapper should not be mixed with common functionality. In example above all 3 sources could be treated as stream so natural solution would be use them all as streams. But even eventually inside wrapper they are used as streams they still require different treatment and actions to work with them. And wrapper takes care about it. You do not care what is wrapped wraps - you just use this wrapped thing in common way which wrapper provides.

In your example we have regular object which encapsulates some data and functionality. This is regular OOP approach. Calling it Wrapper only misguide users who may use this code later.

Comment: How it should be called then? It takes parts send from form and also some variables that I create in main process.

Comment: `  private int numberOfFiles;
    private String pathToWrite;
    private Part part;
    private List attachments; `

`attachments.add(new Zalaczniki(attachmentWrapper.getPathToWrite() + File.separator + fileName));

 `for (Part part : fileParts) {
            attachmentWrapper.setPart(part);`


 ` numberOfFiles = numberOfFiles + 1;
                attachmentWrapper.setNumberOfFiles(numberOfFiles);`

its all from different parts of code
`